# group based on another column

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataframe like this :

```
user_id  items
1        item1
1        item2
1        item3
2        item1
3        item4
3        item2
```

And I need :

```
user_id  number_of_items
1        3
2        1
3        2
```

How can I count the items based on the user_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure user_id is a dimension, not a measure. Then drag it into the rows shelf. Then drag the items field into the columns shelf, right click, and ensure it is being aggregated as a count.